# close a PythonShell on js (electron + flask)

Tags: python, node.js, electron

I've googled around but I cannot find a proper answer, I have to say I'm pretty novice re NodeJS and electron: My problem is that I have connected my electron app with flask using [Python-Shell](https://www.npmjs.com/package/python-shell) but when I close my app, flask is still running in background even if close the terminal.

this is how I connect my app to flask:

```js
var pyshell =  require('python-shell');

  pyshell.PythonShell.run('engine.py',  function  (err, results)  {
    if  (err)  console.log(err);
  });
```

is there any way to "un-run" (close, quit, kill) the pyshell?
I've tried this but is not working:

```js
app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
    pyshell.kill('engine.py'); // <-- I'm guessing here
    app.quit()
  }
```

This is the full code, is quite short, maybe could be useful to identify problems:

```js
const {app, BrowserWindow} = require('electron')

function createWindow () {
  window = new BrowserWindow({width: 800, height: 600})
  window.loadFile('index.html')

  var pyshell =  require('python-shell');

  pyshell.PythonShell.run('engine.py',  function  (err, results)  {
    if  (err)  console.log(err);
  });
}

app.on('ready', createWindow)
app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
    pyshell.kill('engine.py'); // <-- I'm guessing here
    app.quit()
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `pyshell.kill()` didn't actually kill the process rather it signals child process to stop. However, the child fails to stop sometimes.

Try using `tree-kill` npm package to kill that process, it handles such scenarios nicely.

```js
// Declaring tree-kill
var kill = require('tree-kill');

//Killing python process
kill(pyshell.pid);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, unfortunately I archived that project long ago due to other priorities, I will try it as soon as I'll begin working on that again. ;-)